# How to display the data into an app's UI?

Tags: android

I'm trying to build an app that searches restaurants using Android Studio.
I've already finished getting data from google API using json parser.

Now what I need to is to display the information I got from google API into my UI.
Ho can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider starting with an [Android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html).

In the resource folder, under layout there is a activity_main.xml file of some sort. Make a TextView in there. Give it an id using `android:id`.

In your main activity, use `findViewByID(R.id.ID_OF_YOUR_TEXTVIEW)`. You'll have to cast to a TextView before you can use it. Then use the `.setText()` method to update the contents of the view.

Comment: I've figured out how to do that!!Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

Use a `TextView` to write the data from `Google API`.
You can set the values from google API using `TextView.setText()` method